# Error creating junit in groovy project

Tags: eclipse, macos, groovy

I just downloaded groovy plugin for eclipse4.2 from http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/  .I don't have any other installation/ library for groovy on my system. I am able to run groovy programs on my machine in eclipse.
However when I try to **import org.junit.Test**, I get following error.

```
Groovy:class org.junit.Test is not an annotation in @org.junit.Test
Groovy:unable to resolve class org.junit.Test
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the JUnit jars to your classpath.  Select a Project -> Build Path -> Configure build path... -> Librarires -> Add library -> JUnit -> Next -> JUnit 4 -> OK.